# QT tab widget - tab text behaviour on focus

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5, osx-elcapitan

[image]

I am using Qt to create a QT tab widget for a GUI. I cant figure out why the tab currently in focus changes the text to white ? It only happens on the currently selected tab. If I open another window in the same GUI, The text goes back to black.

How can I always force the text to remain black, even when under focus ?

I am using Qt 5.8.0 on a mac OS X running El Capitan 10.11.6.

this is my current style sheet

```
tabWidget1->setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab { background-color: #ACB6B6; }"
                              "QTabBar::tab:focus { color: #000000; }");
```

I've also tried to use this code but it didnt do anything

```
tabWidget1->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
```

Comment: Do you have set a custom qss? Maybe the white color is because it is the current tab and has the focus. If focus is lost the color changes to black?

Comment: yes thats correct. I want it to always remain black, even when its under focus.

Comment: Without seeing your qss all I can say is to use the pseudo state `:focus` and have a look at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar.

Comment: That was helpful. I am not using any QSS currently. I use the default `QTabWidget()` to create a new tabbed widget. No extra QSS except changing the background color with `setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab { background-color: #ACB6B6; }");` What style do I use to change the focus behavior ? I am just getting started with Qt. So Ill need a little more info.

Comment: With setting a style sheet you disable the normal style and have to take care about "everything". Try to extend your style sheet by `QTabBar::tab:focus { color: #000000; }`

Comment: that didnt do anything. My style sheet looks like `tabWidget1->setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab { background-color: #ACB6B6; }"
                              "QTabBar::tab:focus { color: #000000; }");`

Comment: I have also tried using `tabWidget1->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);`. I am not sure if mac OS if overriding this behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tabWidget1->setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab:selected {color: #000000;}");
```

Resolved using the above stylesheet.